# what TimeZone is set implicitly?

Tags: java, date, timezone, simpledateformat

Is there any difference between the following methods,

or taking the default timezone is done implicitly?

```
public static Date stringToDate(String dateStr) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
        simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        return simpleDateFormat.parse(dateStr);
    }
```

and

```
public static Date stringToDate(String dateStr) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
        return simpleDateFormat.parse(dateStr);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The javadoc says that calling `setTimezone` is equivalent to:

```
getCalendar().setTimeZone(zone)
```

And the javadoc for `setCalendar` states:

> Set the calendar to be used by this date format. Initially, the default calendar for the specified or default locale is used.

And the javadoc for [Calendar.getInstance(Locale)` says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance-java.util.Locale-):

> Gets a calendar using the default time zone and specified locale. The Calendar returned is based on the current time in the default time zone with the given locale.

So I would expected the two versions to be equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I took a look [there](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.java) (but maybe there's a better place to look for java sources) and here's what I see :

The constructor `public SimpleDateFormat(String pattern, Locale locale)` you're using calls `initializeCalendar(locale);`

In the [initializeCalendar](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.java#SimpleDateFormat.initializeCalendar%28java.util.Locale%29) method implementation we can see : `calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault(), loc);`

What the `setTimezone` method does :

`calendar.setTimeZone(zone);`

So I guess the default implementation uses `Timezone.getDefault()`, at least in this version of the OpenJDK, so yes, the both methods you mentioned result in the same.